# Confused on adding simple cookie to my jquery to hide spash screen div if already viewed in session

Tags: jquery, cookies, splash-screen

I'm new to jquery and wrote this simple script for a splash screen (just a div z-index 999 over index page).  upon click, I have it set to fade out the div. I'm stuck on adding the script to place a cookie so that if visitor navigates site and returns to the index page, the splash div will not display again in that session.  I assume the cookie, if found, will trigger the div #splash  to display:none.

Can anybody help? Iv read similar posts but they were more advanced scripts so I got confused.

This is my current jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#centered a').click(function() {
  $('#splash').fadeOut(800);
    });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of jquery-cookie, the one you seem to have included? What parts do you have a problem with? Do you have a specific question other than asking us to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.cookie('shown')) {
  $('#splash').hide();
} else {
  $.cookie('shown', 1);
  $('#centered a').click(function() {
    $('#splash').fadeOut(800);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that script but it is not working. the enter button stopped working. it is stuck on splash page now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Is this correct?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($.cookie("test") == null){
    $.cookie("test", "foo");
     $('#centered a').click(function() {
      $('#splash').fadeOut(800);
       });              
} else {
 $('#splash').hide();
  }
   });
</script>
```